# I would like to understand Elastic cache metrics in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, redis, amazon-cloudwatch, metrics, elastic-cache

I would like to understand what all these metrics means in elastic cache metrics in AWS.

- Network Bytes In
- Network Bytes Out
- Network Packets In
- Network Packets Out
- Network Bandwidth In Allowance Exceeded
- Network Bandwidth Out Allowance Exceeded

[image]

I am struggling to understand the meaning of this line in the SS attached above -

> The number of packets queued or dropped because the outbound aggregate
> bandwidth exceeded the maximum for the instance.

I mean how to find what is max/aggregate bandwidth for this instance and how it is related to "Network Bandwidth Out Allowance Exceeded" ? Also what is "Network Baseline Bandwidth" and how is it related to "Network Bandwidth Out Allowance Exceeded".
I am using cache.r7g.large node type.